# What is the Distribution Function of This Random Variable

Tags: probability

> $X$ is a random variable with a continuous distribution function $F$.  Find the distribution function of the random variable $F(X)$.

Suppose that the set $\Omega$ with probability measure $P$ forms the probability space. $X(\omega)$ is some real number.  Therefore, the composite $F(X)(\omega) = P(X(\tau) \le X(\omega))$.  So, this new random variable tell us the probability of getting a $X$ that is smaller than or equal to $X(\omega)$.

1. Since $X$ is continuous, there exists a density function $f$ such that $F(u) = \int_{-\infty}^u \, f(s) \, ds$.
2. So, to obtain $P(F(X)(\omega) \le u)$, we need to add up all the distributions $F(X)(\omega)$ with $X(\omega) \le u$.  Therefore, we have:
   $$F_{F(X)}(u) = P(F(X)(\omega) \le u) = \int_{-\infty}^u \int_{-\infty}^t f(s) \, ds dt$$

This is how I understood the problem, but can you give a better explanation than to "add up" all the distributions $F(X)(\omega)$?  Furthermore, does it mean that the integral $\int_{-\infty}^t f(s) \, ds$ is the density function associated with $F(X)$?

Comment: You are on the wrong track. If $X$ is a random variable and $g:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ is a Borelmeasurable function then $Y=g(X)$ is a random variable and you find its CDF by evaluating $F_Y(u)=P({f(X)\leq u})$ for every fixed $u\in\mathbb R$. Not by inducing any new random variable. This route has to be taking here (i.e. special case $g=F_X$) too. Something else: a distribution can be continuous while a PDF lacks.

Answer (score 0):

For $u\in\left(0,1\right)$ let $x_{u}:=\inf\left\{ x\in\mathbb{R}\mid F\left(x\right)\geq u\right\} $.

Any CDF is right-continuous so that: $$F\left(x\right)\geq u\iff x\geq x_{u}$$
and consequently: $$P\left(F\left(X\right)\geq u\right)=P\left( X\geq x_{u} \right)$$

$F$ is even continuous in this case so that $P\left(X=x_{u} \right)=0$
and $F\left(x_{u}\right)=u$.

This leads us to: $$P\left( F\left(X\right)\geq u \right)=P\left(X\geq x_{u}\right)=P\left(X>x_{u}\right)=1-F\left(x_{u}\right)=1-u$$

justifying the conclusion that $F\left(X\right)$ is uniformly distributed on
$\left[0,1\right]$.